# How to color specific area on mayavi 2d array plotting

Tags: python, plot, visualization, mayavi

I'm using mayavi python library for plotting my 2d elevation array (Extracted from Raster DEM) and its generating 3d visualization using my elevation data perfectly. but i want to show some specific areas on different color.

I'm calculating risky slope areas and i want to show those areas on map using different color.

```
dataset = gdal.Open("elevation.tif", GA_ReadOnly)
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
demArray =  band.ReadAsArray()


mlab.figure(size=(640, 800) , bgcolor=(1, 1, 1))
surf = mlab.surf(demArray, warp_scale=0.1 )
mlab.show()
```

[generated dem using mayavi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyLcv.png)

Could anyone can tell my how to mark specific area using different color in mayavi or any other alternative solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a link for you. I think you will learn more from it.
 (http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.contour3d)
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but it is not what i'm looking for +1

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution. Mayavi library support to add textures to its objects. So by creating blank image and mark specific areas on map, I could create perfectly overlapping texture to mark specific areas on my DEM.